# Adjusting TRP RG957 deep drop rim brakes

Tags: brakes, maintenance, adjustment

I've got a lovely new bike for my daily commute, a Condor Italia. I've done about 1,500 km on it and I need to adjust the brakes. I would expect to just turn this bit:

[image]

But that will not turn, and it even lifts up and drops back down. It's clearly attached to a threaded barrel, so I don't understand why it won't turn, not why it can just lift, given that it is threaded.

How should I be adjusting these brakes?

I may resort to undoing the nut/screw securing the brake cable, pull a bit of cable through, and then tighten the securing screw, but there must be a simpler way to take up the slack from brake pads wearing and cables stretching.

Comment: That's definitely the barrel adjuster. Does the ring need to be pulled up before turning? I.e. does it have a locking mechanism?

Comment: Pretty sure that's a pull-then-turn adjuster; I had the like on an older bike I borrowed, though not that brand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have had these brakes for about 4 years. Turning the adjuster anticlockwise no problem (I have to do this to remove the wheel), but to adjust the brake for wear, you are right, it won't turn clockwise UNLESS I first pull up on the cable to relieve the pressure.

Comment: Concur - its a lockring, to help prevent the brake from adjusting itself over time.  The cable could untension itself without this.